# customized button to go to approval/reject page in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have created a custom button. When user click to the created button, I want it will redirect user (manager) to approval/reject page (as attachment). May I know how?

--[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDv1c.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to query something from ProcessInstanceWorkItem to learn the id of the current step in this particular approval. Have a look at my old answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/12505/799, maybe you can reuse some bits. And read the documentation for the table.